# How is it possible for Alexander to become a chancellor of the Vampire authority?

Tags: plot-explanation, true-blood

In [True Blood: Authority Always Wins](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2170049/), Alexander Drew's character was great and fantastic, he was aged 9 years before being turned (according to [trueblood.wikia](http://trueblood.wikia.com/wiki/Alexander_Drew)).  But it also says that he serves the **Vampire Authority as a Chancellor**.

According to [trueblood.wikia](http://trueblood.wikia.com/wiki/Alexander_Drew):

> Alexander Drew is an angelic looking, yet impetuous vampire. He was
>   turned at the tender age of 9, and serves the Vampire Authority as a
>   Chancellor. He enjoys smoking cigarettes and taunting everyone around
>   him, including his fellow Chancellors.

Other vampires such as [Salome](http://trueblood.wikia.com/wiki/Salome_Agrippa) and [Godric](http://trueblood.wikia.com/wiki/Godric) are aged 2000+ years. So, **how does it possible for Alexander to become a chancellor of the Vampire authority?**

Comment: He is the oldest vampire in the conucil, as the actor said in an interview

Comment: Yeah, you are being somewhat inconsistent in your use of 'age' here, Salome and Godric are were clearly not 2000+ years old when they were turned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[As the wiki states](http://trueblood.wikia.com/wiki/Alexander_Drew), Alexander was aged 9 years old **when he was turned**.

Just like all vampires, they do not age beyond what age they were when turned.  For all we know he could be beyond age of all vampires including Russell (2800 years old), Eric (1100+), and especially Bill (176).

This detail has not been made known yet, however but we can assume he is a very old vampire, if not, very experienced to be on the council.

Comment: FYI:When i was reading trueblood.wikia couple of hours ago they stated he's the oldest member of the authority but now they've removed that!!